# How to implement icon overlay using sharpshell for file and folder in c# windows application

Tags: c#

Used code project link 
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/545781/NET-Shell-Extensions-Shell-Icon-Overlay-Handlers

To check the file icon overlay for read only in the folder

Path :D://folder.txt

After registering with Regasm.exe and restart the PC file icon doesn’t appears

Kindly help us to resolve this issue

We tried on windows 10

Comment: So you are asking for help for a *CodeProject* article? I am not sure this is off-topic by definition, but its not far from it at best

Comment: Hi Michael Randall,  kindly suggest the steps to implement icon overlay in C# like SVN file icons

Comment: Windows 10 and 11 are still limited to 15 (or o be honest only 11) overlay icons, see e.g. https://superuser.com/q/1166577/1080570 for details. So check `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers` what is registered. Mostly OneDrive is "eating up" the most of the available overlay icons.